# How to migrate Linux iptables scripts to OpenBSD/macOS pf

Tags: iptables, vpn, mac-osx, openbsd, pf

I am building a VPN server on macOS based on this instruction:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-18-04-2,
and stuck at configuring firewall part:

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*mangle
-A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
COMMIT

*filter
...

-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in --proto esp -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

I keep reading documents and searching for straightforward examples.
But I couldn't find any useful information. I wonder if anyone
could kindly help me migrate the above code to OpenBSD/macOS `pf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project may help: [Firewall Builder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fwbuilder/)

Comment: This project was abandoned by its developers several years ago.

Comment: :( haven't used it in years, sry about that, may still work but may be behind on config file syntax if any changes.